# Take the difference of all elements of a series with the previous ones in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a dataframe with sorted values labeled by ids and I want to take the difference of the value for the first element of an id with the value of the last elements of the all previous ids. The code below does what I want:

```
import pandas as pd

a = 'a'; b = 'b'; c = 'c'
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[*zip([a, a, a, b, b, c, a], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8])],
                  columns=['id', 'value'])
print(df)
# # take the last value for a particular id
# last_value_for_id = df.loc[df.id.shift(-1) != df.id, :]
# print(last_value_for_id)
current_id = ''; prev_values = {};diffs = {}
for t in df.itertuples(index=False):
    prev_values[t.id] = t.value
    if current_id != t.id:
        current_id = t.id
    else: continue
    for k, v in prev_values.items():
        if k == current_id: continue
        diffs[(k, current_id)] = t.value - v
print(pd.DataFrame(data=diffs.values(), columns=['diff'], index=diffs.keys()))
```

prints:

```
  id  value
0  a      1
1  a      2
2  a      3
3  b      5
4  b      6
5  c      7
6  a      8
     diff
a b     2
  c     4
b c     1
  a     2
c a     1
```

I want to do this in a vectorized manner however. I have found a way of getting the series of last elements as in:

```
# take the last value for a particular id
last_value_for_id = df.loc[df.id.shift(-1) != df.id, :]
print(last_value_for_id)
```

which gives me:

```
  id  value
2  a      3
4  b      6
5  c      7
```

but can't find a way of using this to take the diffs in a vectorized manner

Comment: Could you share an example of how you calculate the output?

Comment: It's the first code snippet

Comment: The printouts are the df and the diffs output I expect

Comment: How long is your data, i.e. how many `id`'s do you have?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how many ids you have, this works with few thousands:

```
# enumerate ids, should be careful
ids = [a,b,c]
num_ids = len(ids)

# compute first and last
f = df.groupby('id').value.agg(['first','last'])

# lower triangle mask
mask = np.array([[i>=j for j in range(num_ids)] for i in range(num_ids)])

# compute diff of first and last, then mask 
diff = np.where(mask, None, f['first'][None,:] - f['last'][:,None])
diff = pd.DataFrame(diff,
                    index = ids,
                    columns = ids)
# stack
diff.stack()
```

output:

```
a  b    2
   c    4
b  c    1
dtype: object
```

### Edit for updated data:

For the updated data, approach is similar if we can create the `f` table:

```
# create blocks of consecutive id
blocks = df['id'].ne(df['id'].shift()).cumsum()

# groupby
groups = df.groupby(blocks)

# create first and last values
df['fv'] = groups.value.transform('first')
df['lv'] = groups.value.transform('last')

# the above f and ids 
# note the column name change
f = df[['id','fv', 'lv']].drop_duplicates()
ids = f['id'].values
num_ids = len(ids)
```

Output:

```
a   b     2
    c     4
    a     5
b   c     1
    a     2
c   a     1
dtype: object
```

If you want to go further and drop the index `(a,a)`, well, I'm so lazy :D.

Comment: I will try and diggest this and come back to you - meanwhile bear in mind that the dfs are actually groups in a larger groupby and that the ids are not sorted them selves and may be repeated in each group - the values are sorted

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I figure that about the `ids`. Since you say `all previous ids`, you should have an order in mind, it may be simply `ids = df['id'].unique()`.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Updated.

Comment: Your output still off a little bit

Answer (score 4):

My method

```
s=df.groupby(df.id.shift().ne(df.id).cumsum()).agg({'id':'first','value':['min','max']})
s.columns=s.columns.droplevel(0)
t=s['min'].values[:,None]-s['max'].values
t=t.astype(float)
```

---

Below are all reshape, to match your output

```
t[np.triu_indices(t.shape[1], 0)] = np.nan
newdf=pd.DataFrame(t,index=s['first'],columns=s['first'])
newdf.values[newdf.index.values[:,None]==newdf.index.values]=np.nan
newdf=newdf.T.stack()
newdf
Out[933]: 
first  first
a      b        2.0
       c        4.0
b      c        1.0
       a        2.0
c      a        1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Aha broadcasting! Very nice - bonus question, as a variation I would like to be able to have a variation where I keep _all_ the diffs from the consecutive ids to the previous ones - in the for loop this is as simple as dropping the `else: continue` statement - how would you moidify the code for this scenario. And n00b question - what's the use of `s.columns=s.columns.droplevel(0)`

Comment: This all has to fit in an groupby apply - I do need the labels but creating a new df everytime and all may prove too performant intensive

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D s used to be a multiple index , I just drop the the first level . About  your additional question check the line I mask the NaN , if you need all previous , just simple remove it , or you can adjust by yourself \

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D so you mean , you have a more big group , and you need groupby ?

Comment: This looks very similar to my approach, except that you used `agg` instead of `transform`, which is a better choice.

Comment: I meant that this df is actually a group in an external df - so all this must be applied in a `groupby.apply` - it makes no difference I just gave it for context

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D you can do 'l= []';`for x , y in outdf.groupby(): df=y.. l append(newdf).`

Comment: I would like to avoid the loop (of course apply might do just this behind the scenes)

Comment: Now I will have to do some timings and get back to you - asap :)